# How to get out a while loop when in Task.Delay

Tags: c#, while-loop, task, abort

I am trying to stop a while loop in my program when an abort key is pressed, and the function running is running a Task.Delay. Unfortunately, even though this must be easy to do I just cannot get it to work for me. Please help.

I have a button that asks the user to confirm they want to run and if yes it comes to the function below and starts to run the RunSequence function. I did have this on a new thread but have now changed it to a Task, I leave the commented out code in just in case I need to run it instead of a task. RunSequence has two parameters the second is what I think I should have and that is a CancellationToken.

```
CancellationTokenSource tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();

    private void ConfirmRunSequence()
    {
    //put it on a thread as the UI is slow to update
    //var thread = new Thread(() => { RunSequence(_filePathName, tokenSource.Token); });
    //thread.IsBackground = true;
    //thread.Start();
    
    Task.Run(() => RunSequence(_filePathName, tokenSource.Token), tokenSource.Token);
    }
```

When the abort button is pressed, we set the Token to cancel and I want to drop out the While loop.

```
private void onAbort()
{
Abort = true; //set to abort sequence
            tokenSource.Cancel();
}
```

I hopefully have the bits above correct, and I think the next bit is what I do not understand. Here I have a CancellationToken called _ct which I believe is tokenSource. My delay here is big so when I see the label update a few times I will then click to abort and it will be inside the delay which I want to cancel. Now this is what I cannot get to work.

I get a red sqiggly under _ct and it says “Cannot convert from System.Threading.CancellationToken to System.Threading.Task.Task”. Ok I read the words but sorry I do not know how to fix it but I also do not know if I did fix it if this is the correct way to get out the While loop, please help.

```
private async void RunSequence(string filePath, CancellationToken _ct)
{
    Int count = 0;

while (!sr.EndOfStream) 
{
    lbl_count = count++;
    await Task.WhenAny(Task.Delay(10000), _ct);
}

lbl_count =”aborted”;
}
```

Amongst the things I have tried is to change from await Task.WhenAny(Task.Delay(10000), _ct); to
Just Task.Delay(10000, _ct) but also no good.

Comment: Simply use `ct.ThrowIfCancellationRequested()` inside your `while` loop

Comment: Do not use a new thread. There is no need when you have tasks available.

Comment: Please show your real code. You can't have `lbl_count = count++;` and `lbl_count =”aborted”;` unless `lbl_count` is an `object`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a small app to show how I got my app to work. Create a small C# Winform .Net with two buttons one to run and one to abort and a label. As there was a request for the code I have included the full example program at Github

https://github.com/zizwiz/Cancellation_Token_Example

I also add a copy of some of the code below:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Cancel_Token_Example
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        CancellationTokenSource tokenSource; // Declare the cancellation token

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btn_run_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();    //Make a new instance
            Task.Run(() => RunSequence(tokenSource.Token)); //Run the task that we need to stop
        }

        private void btn_abort_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            tokenSource.Cancel(); // make the token a cancel token
        }

        private async void RunSequence(CancellationToken _ct)
        {
            int counter = 0;

            while (!_ct.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                // show incrementing number but as we have a task watch for cross threading
                WriteUIData((counter++).ToString());

                try
                {
                    await Task.Delay(1000, _ct); //waits 1 second
                }
                catch
                {
                    // Do nothing just needed so we can exit without exceptions
                }

            }

            if (_ct.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                //report we have cancelled
                WriteUIData("Cancelled");
            }

            tokenSource.Dispose(); //dispose of the token so we can reuse
        }

        private void WriteUIData(String data)
        {
            // Write data to UI but as we have a task watch for cross threading

            if (lbl_output.InvokeRequired)
            {
                lbl_output.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)delegate () { lbl_output.Text = data; });
            }
            else
            {
                lbl_output.Text = data;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I appreciate you were saying thank you to everyone, but this site prides itself on good quality, succinct questions and answers. I've edited your answer to be such. Do feel free to thank everyone in the comments though.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using `Task.Delay`, you can access the [`WaitHandle`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.cancellationtoken.waithandle?view=net-6.0#system-threading-cancellationtoken-waithandle) of the `CancellationToken` and call [`WaitOne`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.waithandle.waitone?view=net-6.0#system-threading-waithandle-waitone(system-int32)) on that, passing a timeout.

The return value from the `WaitOne` operation will be `true` if the token was cancelled and `false` if the timeout was reached, from which you can then take appropriate further action.